# Unable to build FreeRTOS WIN32 demo in Clion

Tags: cmake, clion, freertos

Below is the CmakeLists file that I'm using. I'm using the linker flags from eclipse as it seems to build in eclipse properly.

```
project(new1 LANGUAGES CXX C)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# Compiler options for compiling MinGW targets.
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DprojCOVERAGE_TEST=0 -fmessage-length=0 -Wcast-qual")
#-------------------------------------------------------------

# Linker options for Linking MinGW targets.
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Xlinker -lwinmm")
#-------------------------------------------------------------

include_directories(FreeRTOS/Source/include
                    FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MSVC-MingW
                    /)

add_subdirectory(FreeRTOS/Source)

add_executable(application main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(application kernel)
target_link_libraries(application winmm.lib)
```

The below is the build output

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.1.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\application.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.1.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\application.dir/objects.a
"F:\TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.0.0\PCTools\bin\ar.exe" cr CMakeFiles\application.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\application.dir\objects1.rsp
"F:\TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.0.0\PCTools\bin\g++.exe" -g  -Xlinker -lwinmm -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\application.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o application.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libapplication.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\application.dir\linklibs.rsp
FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MSVC-MingW/libport.a(port.c.obj):port.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `timeGetDevCaps@8'
FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MSVC-MingW/libport.a(port.c.obj):port.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `timeBeginPeriod@4'
FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MSVC-MingW/libport.a(port.c.obj):port.c:(.text+0xd5): undefined reference to `timeGetDevCaps@8'
FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MSVC-MingW/libport.a(port.c.obj):port.c:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `timeEndPeriod@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [application.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/application.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/application.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [application] Error 2
```

Can somebody help please.

Comment: Sorry, @Tsyvarev I forget the important part.

Comment: Variable `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` is not a proper place for `-l` flags intended for link with libraries. Instead use `target_link_libraries` or `link_libraries` command. E.g. `link_libraries(winmm)`.

Comment: Thanks, @Tsyvarev. I used that as well in the bottom but I was linking to the wrong target. winmm is used by a dependency. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there was no issue with linking the winmm library it is just that I'm linking this to a wrong target. It was a dependency of the windows port in freeRTOS/Source/Portable.